# SAML 1x vs SAML 2.0

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have theoretically learned how SAML 2.0 works both in IdP initiated & SP initiated model. Can some one point me how SAML 1x works? I am not seeing any proper material about SAML 101.

And i have some basic question. What is SAML 101, SAML 1.0 & SAML 1.1? Is there any difference between these version?

Comment: http://saml.xml.org/differences-between-saml-2-0-and-1-1

Answer (score 4):

> What is SAML 101, SAML 1.0 & SAML 1.1?

SAML 101 is a way of referring to introductory information about SAML. There is no actual version of SAML that is "101".

SAML 1.0 is the original SAML spec which was fairly quickly superseded by SAML 1.1. Over these two versions, input from other related standards (Shibboleth and Liberty ID-FF) were fed in so that by the time SAML 2.0 arrived on the scene it was the convergence of federation standards at the time - with the exception of WS-Federation.

> Is there any difference between these versions?

Yes, there are a number of differences, here are the biggest:

1. SAML 101 isn't a standard :-)
2. SAML 1.0 is significantly less mature than SAML 1.1 or SAML 2.0
3. SAML 1.1 lacks a robust solution for federated single logout
4. SAML 2.0 is the king of the pile, most widely adopted and most complete

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check [this official tech overview document](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/11511/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-draft-03.pdf) and Chapter 6 give a detail introduction about the different between SAML1 & SAML2

Comment: http://saml.xml.org/saml-2-0-enhancements